# Are Those Inner Products?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inner-products

> Let $C[-1,2]$ be the space of all continuous functions $f:[-1,2]\to \mathbb{C}$.
>
> Which of the following define an inner product on $C[-1,2]$ and which do not?
>
> 1. $\langle f,g\rangle =\int_{-1}^{2}f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt+f(-\frac{1}{2})\overline{g(-\frac{1}{2})}$
> 2. $\langle f,g\rangle =3\int_{-1}^{2}f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$
> 3. $\langle f,g\rangle =f(0)\overline{g(0)}+f(1)\overline{g(1)}$

It seems that all are inner products.

I am just not sure in the case of 1 if it is linear in the first argument

and in case 3, if it is an inner product can we conclude that $\langle f,g\rangle =c$ where $c\in \mathbb{R^{+}}$?

Comment: 3 is obviously not an inner product. It disobeys positive-definiteness.

Comment: @edm Doesn't $<f,f>=|f(0|^2+|f(1)|^2\geq 0$ ?

Comment: @gbox, that's positive *semi-*definiteness. Also, to be clear, you do not need that $\langle f, g \rangle \in \mathbb R$; these are clearly inner products over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: For a concrete example, take $f(x) = x(x-1)$. It has $\langle f, f\rangle = 0$ according to 3, but it is clearly not the zero function.